# Retrieving records from a database in C# 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net-3.5

I need syntax help with the following code logic:

I have a code block that gets email address from the database. The email addresses need to be assigned to a string variable strEmailAddress with a comma seperation

My code is:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
string sqlEmailAddress = "usp_Get_Email_Address";
SqlCommand cmdEmailAddr = new SqlCommand(sqlEmailAddress, conn);
cmdEmailAddr.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
con.Open();
SqlDataReader sqlDREmailAddr = cmdEmailAddr.ExecuteReader();
```

How can I loop through the records and store the results in strEmailAddress seperated by comma?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`SqlDataReader.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read.aspx) method:

```
while (sqlDREmailAddr.Read())
{
 ...
 // Assumes only one column is returned with the email address
 strEmailAddress = sqlDREmailAddr.GetString(0);
}
```

Comment: I don't know what your stored procedure returns. How does it show in the datarecord?

Comment: it returns a string; there can be more than one record returned;

Comment: Answer updated. Read up on SqlDataReader methods, you might learn something.

Answer (score 5):

```
while (sqlDREmailAddr.Read())
{
    //...process each row here
}
```

I would also wrap the reader in a `using` statement to make sure it is closed properly:

```
using (SqlDataReader sqlDREmailAddr = cmdEmailAddr.ExecuteReader())
{
}
```

Depending on what the columns in your dataset is named, reading values from each record will look something like this (**update**: now with all addresses merged):

```
var emailAddress = new StringBuilder();
var emailAddressOrdinal = sqlDREmailAddr.GetOrdinal("EmailAddress");
while (sqlDREmailAddr.Read())
{
    if (emailAddress.Length > 0)
        emailAddress.Append(',');
    emailAddress.Append(sqlDREmailAddr.GetString(emailAddressOrdinal));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while (sqlDREmailAddr.Read())
  {
    // handle row here
  }
```

Comment: The test for HasRows is rather superfluous since the first call to `Read()` will return false if there are no rows.

Comment: I thought so too, I originally had my answer without it....but on MSDN's example they did both. So I put both. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're looking for....

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn)){
   string sqlEmailAddress = "usp_Get_Email_Address";

   using (SqlCommand cmdEmailAddr = new SqlCommand(sqlEmailAddress, conn)){
       cmdEmailAddr.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

       conn.Open(); // Typo Glitch!

       using (SqlDataReader sqlDREmailAddr = cmdEmailAddr.ExecuteReader()){

           while(sqlDREmailAddr.Read()){

              if (!sqlDREmailAddr.IsDBNull(sqlDREmailAddr.GetOrdinal("emailAddr"))){

                 // HANDLE THE DB NULL...

              }else{

                 strEmailAddress = sqlDREmailAddr.GetSqlString(sqlDREmailAddr.GetOrdinal("emailAddr"));

                 // Do something with strEmailAddr...

              }
           }
       }
   }

}
```

Notice:

- A typo glitch on the `conn` variable...
- A check is made to ensure that the Database value returned is not NULL
- A call is made to `GetOrdinal` to return the column based on `emailAddr` string value that corresponds to the column from the query for SQL Select...which is an `int` type) as the parameter for `GetSqlString`..

**Edit:** Thanks to ***John Saunders*** for pointing out a blooper!

**Edit#2:** Thanks to Peter Lillevold for pointing out a mis-spelling...

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: Move your `GetOrdinal`s out of the loop. And `Read` is with capital R :)

Comment: @Peter Lillevold: sigh...wish there was some intelligent spell checker to spot that one... yeah... good catch there.... :) nice one+1 for your comment!